# Method not found: 'System.Threading.Monitor.Enter'

Tags: mono

The last person who asked this question asked it a) 4 years ago and b) likely in a different scenario. I'm currently using Lidgren.Network for a game, who has the server-side somewhat fleshed out. I have been trying to import Lidgren into Unity, and so I've compiled Lidgren into Mono/4.5. However, Unity throws a MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Monitor.Enter' at Lidgren.Network.NetPeer.Start(). The exact same code runs perfectly fine in Visual Studio, compiled as .net 4.5, but somehow Mono or Unity don't like it. Any solutions?

Comment: Have you checked the 4th comment on [this page](https://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/wiki/Unity3D)?